# Dynamic legend with multiple layers in leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a choropleth map I am putting together with two different layers. each layer has its own symbolization and legend. I have so far been successful in having the legend change when a new layer is turned on, however if a layer is turned off, the legend does not change to match the remaining layer. Additionally, if all layers are turned off, the legend will remain for whatever layer last activated a legend change.

my code that is working for the layer change so far is:

```
map.on('overlayadd', function (eventLayer) 
{
    if (eventLayer.name === 'Housing'){
        map.removeControl(currentLegend );
        currentLegend = houselegend;
        houselegend.addTo(map);
    }
    else if (eventLayer.name === 'Families') {
        map.removeControl(currentLegend );
        currentLegend = childlegend;
        childlegend.addTo(map);
    }
})
```

The code I have tried so far to make the legend change when a layer is removed or all layers are removed is:

```
function legendChange(e) {
    if (map.hasLayer(Families) && !map.hasLayer(Housing)){
        map.removeControl(currentLegend );
        currentLegend = childlegend;
        childlegend.addTo(map);
    }
    else if (map.hasLayer(Housing) && !map.hasLayer(Families)){
        map.removeControl(currentLegend );
        currentLegend = houselegend;
        houselegend.addTo(map);
    }
    else if (!map.hasLayer(Housing) && !map.hasLayer(Families)){
        map.removeControl(currentLegend );
    }
}
```

The map loads right now, so I'm confident my syntax is close and that the problem is likely with my logic.

Answer (score 5):

I think the first problem is your `currentLegend` variable. Whenever you add a layer this variable gets overwritten, either with `houselegend` or `childlegend`. Let's say you activate Families and then Housing, your `currentLegend` is now `houselegend`.

Now you deactive the Families layers, but your Housing legend is removed, and `currentLegend` is set to `houselegend` again. You now remove the Housing layer and legend, but it fails because `houselegend` is already removed, `childlegend` stays.

The second problem is that the conditions in your `if` code are mutually exclusive in handling the layer legends. It allows only one legend to be active at a time, whenever a layer is added a legend is removed.

One way to solve and simplify this would be to create a mapping between layers and legends. Add and remove legends according to the layer name taken from the event.

```
var layerToLegendMapping={
  "Housing": houselegend,
  "Families": childlegend
}
function legendAdd(event) {
  var layername = event.name;
  map.addControl(layerToLegendMapping[layername]);
}
function legendRemove(event) {
  var layername = event.name;
  map.removeControl(layerToLegendMapping[layername]);
}
map.on('overlayadd',legendAdd);
map.on('overlayremove',legendRemove);
```